# From a codepen, why the button doesn't appear?

Tags: javascript, button

I tried to re-do this codepen : https://codepen.io/jakaric/pen/mjJQvg
But, differently from you can see it here (in the run result), the liquid "Pretty little button" doesn't appear in my local files.

On Codepen, there is no library mentionned in JS' parameters, so i don't know what could be the problem... :(

Does anyone could explain me why this liquid "Pretty little button", doesn't appear in my local files (as on codepen's page, or here on the stack overflow's editor) ?

Thank you so much for your reading, and your help.

```js
   const LiquidButton = class LiquidButton {
            constructor(svg) {
                const options = svg.dataset;
                this.id = this.constructor.id || (this.constructor.id = 1);
                this.constructor.id++;
                this.xmlns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
                this.tension = options.tension * 1 || 0.4;
                this.width = options.width * 1 || 200;
                this.height = options.height * 1 || 50;
                this.margin = options.margin || 40;
                this.hoverFactor = options.hoverFactor || -0.1;
                this.gap = options.gap || 5;
                this.debug = options.debug || false;
                this.forceFactor = options.forceFactor || 0.2;
                this.color1 = options.color1 || '#36DFE7';
                this.color2 = options.color2 || '#8F17E1';
                this.color3 = options.color3 || '#BF09E6';
                this.textColor = options.textColor || '#FFFFFF';
                this.text = options.text || 'Button';
                this.svg = svg;
                this.layers = [{
                    points: [],
                    viscosity: 0.5,
                    mouseForce: 100,
                    forceLimit: 2,
                }, {
                    points: [],
                    viscosity: 0.8,
                    mouseForce: 150,
                    forceLimit: 3,
                }];
                for (let layerIndex = 0; layerIndex < this.layers.length; layerIndex++) {
                    const layer = this.layers[layerIndex];
                    layer.viscosity = options['layer-' + (layerIndex + 1) + 'Viscosity'] * 1 || layer.viscosity;
                    layer.mouseForce = options['layer-' + (layerIndex + 1) + 'MouseForce'] * 1 || layer.mouseForce;
                    layer.forceLimit = options['layer-' + (layerIndex + 1) + 'ForceLimit'] * 1 || layer.forceLimit;
                    layer.path = document.createElementNS(this.xmlns, 'path');
                    this.svg.appendChild(layer.path);
                }
                this.wrapperElement = options.wrapperElement || document.body;
                if (!this.svg.parentElement) {
                    this.wrapperElement.append(this.svg);
                }

                this.svgText = document.createElementNS(this.xmlns, 'text');
                this.svgText.setAttribute('x', '50%');
                this.svgText.setAttribute('y', '50%');
                this.svgText.setAttribute('dy', ~~(this.height / 8) + 'px');
                this.svgText.setAttribute('font-size', ~~(this.height / 3));
                this.svgText.style.fontFamily = 'sans-serif';
                this.svgText.setAttribute('text-anchor', 'middle');
                this.svgText.setAttribute('pointer-events', 'none');
                this.svg.appendChild(this.svgText);

                this.svgDefs = document.createElementNS(this.xmlns, 'defs')
                this.svg.appendChild(this.svgDefs);

                this.touches = [];
                this.noise = options.noise || 0;
                document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', this.touchHandler);
                document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', this.touchHandler);
                document.body.addEventListener('touchend', this.clearHandler);
                document.body.addEventListener('touchcancel', this.clearHandler);
                this.svg.addEventListener('mousemove', this.mouseHandler);
                this.svg.addEventListener('mouseout', this.clearHandler);
                this.initOrigins();
                this.animate();
            }

            get mouseHandler() {
                return (e) => {
                    this.touches = [{
                        x: e.offsetX,
                        y: e.offsetY,
                        force: 1,
                    }];
                };
            }

            get touchHandler() {
                return (e) => {
                    this.touches = [];
                    const rect = this.svg.getBoundingClientRect();
                    for (let touchIndex = 0; touchIndex < e.changedTouches.length; touchIndex++) {
                        const touch = e.changedTouches[touchIndex];
                        const x = touch.pageX - rect.left;
                        const y = touch.pageY - rect.top;
                        if (x > 0 && y > 0 && x < this.svgWidth && y < this.svgHeight) {
                            this.touches.push({
                                x,
                                y,
                                force: touch.force || 1
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    e.preventDefault();
                };
            }

            get clearHandler() {
                return (e) => {
                    this.touches = [];
                };
            }

            get raf() {
                return this.__raf || (this.__raf = (
                    window.requestAnimationFrame ||
                    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                    function (callback) {
                        setTimeout(callback, 10)
                    }
                ).bind(window));
            }

            distance(p1, p2) {
                return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p1.x - p2.x, 2) + Math.pow(p1.y - p2.y, 2));
            }

            update() {
                for (let layerIndex = 0; layerIndex < this.layers.length; layerIndex++) {
                    const layer = this.layers[layerIndex];
                    const points = layer.points;
                    for (let pointIndex = 0; pointIndex < points.length; pointIndex++) {
                        const point = points[pointIndex];
                        const dx = point.ox - point.x + (Math.random() - 0.5) * this.noise;
                        const dy = point.oy - point.y + (Math.random() - 0.5) * this.noise;
                        const d = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
                        const f = d * this.forceFactor;
                        point.vx += f * ((dx / d) || 0);
                        point.vy += f * ((dy / d) || 0);
                        for (let touchIndex = 0; touchIndex < this.touches.length; touchIndex++) {
                            const touch = this.touches[touchIndex];
                            let mouseForce = layer.mouseForce;
                            if (
                                touch.x > this.margin &&
                                touch.x < this.margin + this.width &&
                                touch.y > this.margin &&
                                touch.y < this.margin + this.height
                            ) {
                                mouseForce *= -this.hoverFactor;
                            }
                            const mx = point.x - touch.x;
                            const my = point.y - touch.y;
                            const md = Math.sqrt(mx * mx + my * my);
                            const mf = Math.max(-layer.forceLimit, Math.min(layer.forceLimit, (mouseForce *
                                touch.force) / md));
                            point.vx += mf * ((mx / md) || 0);
                            point.vy += mf * ((my / md) || 0);
                        }
                        point.vx *= layer.viscosity;
                        point.vy *= layer.viscosity;
                        point.x += point.vx;
                        point.y += point.vy;
                    }
                    for (let pointIndex = 0; pointIndex < points.length; pointIndex++) {
                        const prev = points[(pointIndex + points.length - 1) % points.length];
                        const point = points[pointIndex];
                        const next = points[(pointIndex + points.length + 1) % points.length];
                        const dPrev = this.distance(point, prev);
                        const dNext = this.distance(point, next);

                        const line = {
                            x: next.x - prev.x,
                            y: next.y - prev.y,
                        };
                        const dLine = Math.sqrt(line.x * line.x + line.y * line.y);

                        point.cPrev = {
                            x: point.x - (line.x / dLine) * dPrev * this.tension,
                            y: point.y - (line.y / dLine) * dPrev * this.tension,
                        };
                        point.cNext = {
                            x: point.x + (line.x / dLine) * dNext * this.tension,
                            y: point.y + (line.y / dLine) * dNext * this.tension,
                        };
                    }
                }
            }

            animate() {
                this.raf(() => {
                    this.update();
                    this.draw();
                    this.animate();
                });
            }

            get svgWidth() {
                return this.width + this.margin * 2;
            }

            get svgHeight() {
                return this.height + this.margin * 2;
            }

            draw() {
                for (let layerIndex = 0; layerIndex < this.layers.length; layerIndex++) {
                    const layer = this.layers[layerIndex];
                    if (layerIndex === 1) {
                        if (this.touches.length > 0) {
                            while (this.svgDefs.firstChild) {
                                this.svgDefs.removeChild(this.svgDefs.firstChild);
                            }
                            for (let touchIndex = 0; touchIndex < this.touches.length; touchIndex++) {
                                const touch = this.touches[touchIndex];
                                const gradient = document.createElementNS(this.xmlns, 'radialGradient');
                                gradient.id = 'liquid-gradient-' + this.id + '-' + touchIndex;
                                const start = document.createElementNS(this.xmlns, 'stop');
                                start.setAttribute('stop-color', this.color3);
                                start.setAttribute('offset', '0%');
                                const stop = document.createElementNS(this.xmlns, 'stop');
                                stop.setAttribute('stop-color', this.color2);
                                stop.setAttribute('offset', '100%');
                                gradient.appendChild(start);
                                gradient.appendChild(stop);
                                this.svgDefs.appendChild(gradient);
                                gradient.setAttribute('cx', touch.x / this.svgWidth);
                                gradient.setAttribute('cy', touch.y / this.svgHeight);
                                gradient.setAttribute('r', touch.force);
                                layer.path.style.fill = 'url(#' + gradient.id + ')';
                            }
                        } else {
                            layer.path.style.fill = this.color2;
                        }
                    } else {
                        layer.path.style.fill = this.color1;
                    }
                    const points = layer.points;
                    const commands = [];
                    commands.push('M', points[0].x, points[0].y);
                    for (let pointIndex = 1; pointIndex < points.length; pointIndex += 1) {
                        commands.push('C',
                            points[(pointIndex + 0) % points.length].cNext.x,
                            points[(pointIndex + 0) % points.length].cNext.y,
                            points[(pointIndex + 1) % points.length].cPrev.x,
                            points[(pointIndex + 1) % points.length].cPrev.y,
                            points[(pointIndex + 1) % points.length].x,
                            points[(pointIndex + 1) % points.length].y
                        );
                    }
                    commands.push('Z');
                    layer.path.setAttribute('d', commands.join(' '));
                }
                this.svgText.textContent = this.text;
                this.svgText.style.fill = this.textColor;
            }

            createPoint(x, y) {
                return {
                    x: x,
                    y: y,
                    ox: x,
                    oy: y,
                    vx: 0,
                    vy: 0,
                };
            }

            initOrigins() {
                this.svg.setAttribute('width', this.svgWidth);
                this.svg.setAttribute('height', this.svgHeight);
                for (let layerIndex = 0; layerIndex < this.layers.length; layerIndex++) {
                    const layer = this.layers[layerIndex];
                    const points = [];
                    for (let x = ~~(this.height / 2); x < this.width - ~~(this.height / 2); x += this.gap) {
                        points.push(this.createPoint(
                            x + this.margin,
                            this.margin
                        ));
                    }
                    for (let alpha = ~~(this.height * 1.25); alpha >= 0; alpha -= this.gap) {
                        const angle = (Math.PI / ~~(this.height * 1.25)) * alpha;
                        points.push(this.createPoint(
                            Math.sin(angle) * this.height / 2 + this.margin + this.width - this.height /
                            2,
                            Math.cos(angle) * this.height / 2 + this.margin + this.height / 2
                        ));
                    }
                    for (let x = this.width - ~~(this.height / 2) - 1; x >= ~~(this.height / 2); x -= this.gap) {
                        points.push(this.createPoint(
                            x + this.margin,
                            this.margin + this.height
                        ));
                    }
                    for (let alpha = 0; alpha <= ~~(this.height * 1.25); alpha += this.gap) {
                        const angle = (Math.PI / ~~(this.height * 1.25)) * alpha;
                        points.push(this.createPoint(
                            (this.height - Math.sin(angle) * this.height / 2) + this.margin - this.height /
                            2,
                            Math.cos(angle) * this.height / 2 + this.margin + this.height / 2
                        ));
                    }
                    layer.points = points;
                }
            }
        }


        const redraw = () => {
            button.initOrigins();
        };

        const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('liquid-button');
        for (let buttonIndex = 0; buttonIndex < buttons.length; buttonIndex++) {
            const button = buttons[buttonIndex];
            button.liquidButton = new LiquidButton(button);
        }
```

```css
@import: url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);
* {
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        color: #fff;
    }

    body {
        background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3C?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?%3E%3C!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 22.0.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0) --%3E%3Csvg version='1.1' id='Layer_1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' viewBox='0 0 1366 768' style='enable-background:new 0 0 1366 768;' xml:space='preserve'%3E%3Cstyle type='text/css'%3E .st0{clip-path:url(%23SVGID_2_);} .st1{fill:url(%23SVGID_3_);} .st2{fill:url(%23SVGID_4_);} .st3{fill:url(%23SVGID_5_);} .st4{fill:none;} .st5{fill:url(%23SVGID_6_);} %3C/style%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Crect id='SVGID_1_' x='0' y='-1' width='1366' height='769'/%3E%3C/defs%3E%3CclipPath id='SVGID_2_'%3E%3Cuse xlink:href='%23SVGID_1_' style='overflow:visible;'/%3E%3C/clipPath%3E%3Cg class='st0'%3E%3Cg%3E%3ClinearGradient id='SVGID_3_' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse' x1='0.5951' y1='605.4057' x2='0.5951' y2='605.4057' gradientTransform='matrix(6.123234e-17 -1 1 6.123234e-17 -767.4451 768.6354)'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' style='stop-color:%232AA9FF'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' style='stop-color:%233FFFE3'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3Cpath class='st1' d='M-162,768'/%3E%3Cg%3E%3ClinearGradient id='SVGID_4_' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse' x1='1207.1147' y1='29.5433' x2='216.3272' y2='601.5747'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' style='stop-color:%232AA9FF'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' style='stop-color:%233FFFE3'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3Cpath class='st2' d='M1188.6,205.5c-399.2,0-467.8-206-467.8-206H-0.5v7V226c0.5,0,1,0,1.5,0c16.7,0,33,1.5,48.8,4.3 C324.4,255.7,539.5,486.4,540,767.5h648.6C1188.6,767.5,1587.8,205.5,1188.6,205.5z'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3ClinearGradient id='SVGID_5_' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse' x1='392.0089' y1='541.6735' x2='-392.0089' y2='994.3265' gradientTransform='matrix(-1 0 0 -1 0 1536)'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' style='stop-color:%232AA9FF'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' style='stop-color:%233FFFE3'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3Cellipse class='st3' cx='0' cy='768' rx='447' ry='469'/%3E%3Crect x='-1' y='-1' class='st4' width='1367' height='769'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3ClinearGradient id='SVGID_6_' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse' x1='254.0246' y1='595.4224' x2='-267.3227' y2='896.4224' gradientTransform='matrix(-0.9659 0.2588 -0.2588 -0.9659 186.6364 1490.2266)'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' style='stop-color:%232AA9FF'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' style='stop-color:%233FFFE3'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3Cpolygon class='st5' points='-90,1103.7 245.8,1013.8 335.7,678 90,432.3 -245.8,522.2 -335.7,858 '/%3E%3Crect x='0' y='-1' class='st4' width='1366' height='769'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");

        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }
    #logo {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
    nav {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding: 50px;
    }

    nav ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    nav ul a {
        color: #000;
        padding: 0 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .container {
        text-align: center;
        width: 60%;
        margin: 110px auto;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 3.5em;
        font-weight: 700;
    }

    p {
        font-size: 1.3em;
        line-height: 1.4em;
        letter-spacing: 1.7px;
        max-width: 80%;
        margin: auto;
    }
svg {
        cursor: pointer;
        user-select: none;
    }
```

```html
<header>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-fontselect/0.13.4/angular-fontselect.css"/>
        <nav>
            <a href="#" id="logo">Liquid</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">about us</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Headline</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint optio inventore, totam, sapiente commodi exercitationem
                explicabo ipsam quos obcaecati rem eveniet et laudantium porro vel unde harum deserunt nulla nostrum?</p>
          <svg class="liquid-button" data-text="Pretty little button" data-force-factor="0.1" data-layer-1-viscosity="0.5" data-layer-2-viscosity="0.4"
                data-layer-1-mouse-force="400" data-layer-2-mouse-force="500" data-layer-1-force-limit="1" data-layer-2-force-limit="2"
                data-color1="#4DE7BF" data-color2="#51EDE9" data-color3="#2A62F4"></svg>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Comment: I see it on the codepen page....

Comment: Yes, this is why i don't understand why i can't see it on stackoverflow's editor or in my local files ???

Comment: So what are the errors in the console for you local version? Also weird you have angular, vue, knockout, and react on same page.

Comment: All-right, i removed all the angular, vue, knockout and react. I was just trying tu put in lot of libraries, in case of... but it wasn't a good idea. I come back with the console errors in my local version.

Comment: OK, i work on VisualStudio, i did "Run"/"Start Debugging"/"Chrome-Preview". Then i had a new window with a big red cross with this message : "Variable ${workspaceFolder} can not be resolved. Please open a folder." Under this message there are two buttons. On the first one it's written "Open launch.json" on the other one it's written "Cancel"

Comment: OK, i made a mistake on the stack-overflow's editor i copied 2 times the css code instead of putting the js code. So it was without js code. But now it's all-right, it works perfectly on stack overflow's editor.

Comment: I go back to my local files to try to see what i could have done wrong.

Comment: OK, i fixed it on my local files, thank you very much !

Comment: The problem is that i put the JS code in the header, instead to putting it down, just in front of the balise "</main>" or "</body>

Comment: Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

I found why it didn't work on my local files :

The problem is that i put the JS code in the header, instead to putting it down at the bottom, just in front of the balise "`</main>`" or "`</body>`"

Thank you very much for your attention, i will be carefull with this kind of problem now !